# Node.js check if one substring contains something from another substring

Tags: node.js, substring, contains, indexof, discord.js

So, i want to check if one substring contains something from another substring, basically if atleast one word matches. I'm developing discord bot and need it to block certain words.

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
let args2 = args.slice(0).join(' ');
fs.readFile('./words.json','utf8', (err,data4) => {
if (err) throw err;


   if (data4.indexOf(args2))
   {
     message.channel.send("contains");
   }
```

now, problem is that it returns true always.
In words i have list like this right now:

test

justatest

and when my message contains one of these words, for example: "This is a test sentence". It contains word "test" and i want it to detect it, but i can't get it working with indexOf().

Comment: indexOf returns the index position if it finds a match and -1 if it doesn't find a match. so your code should be something like if (data4.indexOf(args2) !== -1)  which means it found a match.

Comment: It works if i write just "test", if i write "This is a test", it isn't working.

Comment: It works always because data4.indexOf(args2) always returns a value. It is either -1 or actual number. positive cases will always work.  With your current code, negative cases also works because you are not checking for -1. If you check for -1, then negative cases will not flow inside the if block.  
if (data4.indexOf(args2)) just checks whether the value is not null or undefined.since -1 is not null or undefined, it goes inside the block.

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: you can print the value, something like console.log(data4.indexOf(args2)) and see what value it prints. if you debug you will be able to understand. Good luck.

Comment: Found the answer already?